# How to highlight a blank field in a <form> using listeners?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My knowledge of listeners is new. I understand what they're for but not 100% on how to set them up. I'm working on a basic project that needs a listener so that when a blank form is submitted it will highlight the text boxes red. The red boxes will then go away when the text is typed into the boxes. I believe I have everything setup but the listeners. Feel free to correct if im wrong but im looking for assistance with a couple steps. I know that im close or at least feel that this is the only step I dont quite understand yet:

Set up a listener on the form’s submit event so that the code prevents submission of the form (preventDefault()) if either the title or description field is left blank or the accept license box is not checked, but otherwise submits the form.

Enhance the JavaScript so that blank fields trigger a change in the appearance
of the form (using the style defined earlier).

Add another listener to the fields so that when the user types into a field
(changed event) JavaScript removes the red color you just added.

Here is my code:

```js
function isBlank(inputField){
    if(inputField.type=="checkbox"){
 if(inputField.checked)
     return false;
 return true;
    }
    if (inputField.value==""){
 return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function makeRed(inputDiv){
    inputDiv.style.backgroundColor="#AA0000";
 inputDiv.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="#AA0000";
 inputDiv.parentNode.style.color="#FFFFFF";  
}
function makeClean(inputDiv){
 inputDiv.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF";
 inputDiv.parentNode.style.color="#000000";  
}

window.onload = function(){
    var mainForm = document.getElementById("mainForm");
    var requiredInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".required");
    for (var i=0; i < requiredInputs.length; i++){
 requiredInputs[i].onfocus = function(){
     this.style.backgroundColor = "#EEEE00";
 }
    }
    mainForm.onsubmit = function(e){
 var requiredInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".required");
 for (var i=0; i < requiredInputs.length; i++){
     if( isBlank(requiredInputs[i]) ){
  e.preventDefault();
  makeRed(requiredInputs[i]);
     }
     else{
  makeClean(requiredInputs[i]);
     }
 }
    }
}
```

```css
/* general text formatting */

h1, h2, h3, nav, footer {
 font-family: Georgia, Cambria, "Times New Roman", serif;
}
body {
   font-family: "Lucida Sans", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 85%;
}

table {
   border-collapse: collapse; 
   border-spacing: 0;   
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
table tbody td{
   /* border: 1pt solid #95BEF0;   */
   line-height: 1.5em;
   vertical-align: top;
   padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
}

legend {
   background-color: #EBF4FB ;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 90%;
   padding: 0.25em;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 100%;
}
fieldset {
   margin: 1em auto;
   background-color: #FAFCFF;
   width: 60%;
}
form p {
   margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.box {
   border: 1pt solid #95BEF0;
   padding: 0.5em;
   margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

.rectangle {
   background-color: #EBF4FB;
   padding: 0.5em;
}
.centered {
   text-align: center;
}

.rounded, .rounded:hover {
   border: 1px solid #172d6e;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #0e1d45;
   border-radius: 5px;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   background-color: #8c9cbf;
   padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
   margin: 0.3em;
   width: 7em;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #72b9eb, 0 1px 4px 0 #b3b3b3;
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #72b9eb, 0 1px 4px 0 #b3b3b3; 
}
.rounded:hover {
   background-color: #7f8dad;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Chapter 6</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Lab5.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script/Lab5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <form method="get" action="" id="mainForm"> "Your original line of code replaced with your line of code from Lab 4 -->
<form method="get" action="http://www.randyconnolly.com/tests/process.php">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Photo Details</legend>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
               <p>
               <label>Title</label><br/>
               <input type="text" name="title" size="80" class="required" />
               </p>
               <p>
               <label>Description</label><br/>
               <textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="61" class="required">
               </textarea>
               </p>            
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> 
               <p> 
               <label>Continent</label><br/>
               <select name="continent">
                  <option>Choose continent</option> 
                  <option>Africa</option>
                  <option>Asia</option>
                  <option>Europe</option>
                  <option>North America</option>
                  <option>South America</option>
               </select>
               </p>
               <p> 
               <label>Country</label><br/>
               <select name="country">
                  <option>Choose country</option> 
                  <option>Canada</option>
                  <option>Mexico</option>
                  <option>United States</option>
               </select>
               </p>
               <p> 
               <label>City</label><br/>               
               <input type="text" name="city" list="cities"  size="40"/>
               <datalist id="cities">
                  <option>Calgary</option>                
                  <option>Montreal</option>
                  <option>Toronto</option>                  
                  <option>Vancouver</option>
               </datalist>
               </p>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="box">
                  <label>Copyright? </label><br/>
                  <input type="radio" name="copyright" value="1">All rights reserved<br/>
                  <input type="radio" name="copyright" value="2" checked>Creative Commons<br/>
               </div>
               <div class="box">
                  <label>Creative Commons Types </label><br/>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="cc" >Attribution <br/>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="cc" >Noncommercial <br/>    
                  <input type="checkbox" name="cc" >No Derivative Works <br/>  
                  <input type="checkbox" name="cc" >Share Alike
               </div>               
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2" >
            <div class="rectangle"> 
               <label>I accept the software license</label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="accept" class="required">
            </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                  <p>
                  <label>Rate this photo: </label><br/>
                  <input type="number" min="1" max="5" name="rate" />  
                  </p>                  
                  <p>
                  <label>Color Collection: </label><br/>
                  <input type="color"  name="color" />   
                  </p>                  
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="box">
                  <p>
                  <label>Date Taken: </label><br/>
                  <input type="date"  name="date" />   
                  </p>
                  <p>
                  <label>Time Taken: </label><br/>
                  <input type="time"  name="time" />                    
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
               <div class="rectangle centered"> 
                  <input type="submit" class="rounded"> <input type="reset" value="Clear Form" class="rounded">      
               </div>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Before you get to to the JavaScript, you need to switch over the HTML for the `<form>` tag: you currently have a `<form>` tag with no id, but the HTML comment shows the tag you really need with `id="mainForm"`

Comment: Do you just wanna highlight a blank field? If so, it can be done in the <form> tag itself. You don't need to implement javascript.

Comment: I need to use javascript on this one unfortunately. my understanding of listeners and events is minimal. I get what they do I just don't know how to quite use them if im being up front

Answer (score 0):

**On submit** (`object` is your form):

```
object.onsubmit = function(){
    //things you want to happen on form submit
};
```

In order to **listen to inputs** (`object` is an input field), try this:

```
object.oninput = function(){
    //things that happen during input
};
```

PS: This will be much easier using jQuery.

Comment: I did find this example: <form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>                 Do I add this right below my html body? Also I apologize but I just need to make sure this matches the name in my js as well right? This part for me is really js 101. I've read alot but it hasnt quite clicked yet for me

Comment: 1) I would avoid using javaScript inside html tags.
2) The code I've posted should be a part of a javaScript file that should be loaded in yout HTML using the `<script>` tage

Comment: ok sense I have this in my java script:  mainForm.onsubmit = function(e){
 var requiredInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".required");
 for (var i=0; i < requiredInputs.length; i++){
     if( isBlank(requiredInputs[i]) ){
  e.preventDefault();
  makeRed(requiredInputs[i]);
     }
     else{
  makeClean(requiredInputs[i]);
     }

Comment: All I need to do then is after the body in the html I would use something similar to this? my js file name is Lab5.js but it looks like this is referring to elements in which case im not exactly sure how to reference it unless I call upon it by:  mainForm.onsubmit : <script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
</script>

Comment: Sure thing. I apologize I dont know how to respond to you by entering my code without exceeding max characters that being said in my initial questions I have my code in the three boxes as javascript, css, and html in order. If you need me to get the code to you differently in the comments I will be more than happy to however. I appreciate it

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll be on it

Comment: No problem. I appreciate it.

Comment: I see you didn't give your form a class nor an id. First, give it one of them (suppose, an id='myform') and then try this code
`document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    //your code here
});`

Comment: By the way, you can valid your form using HTML5 validation. 
Check this article http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Comment: Something like this?    </head>
document.querySelector("mainForm.onsubmit").addEventListener("submit", function(e){var requiredInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".required");
 for (var i=0; i < requiredInputs.length; i++){
     if( isBlank(requiredInputs[i]) ){
  e.preventDefault();
  makeRed(requiredInputs[i]);
     }
     else{
  makeClean(requiredInputs[i]);});
<body>

Comment: Check this fiddle I made -  https://jsfiddle.net/g80caa61/
You can see the on submit, it alerts. now instead of alerting, add the code you want

Comment: Thank you. I made a fiddle back with the changes I made. Does this look correct?: https://jsfiddle.net/n3xcppLb/